# Angular Unit Test Interfaces in Karma Jasmine : Cannot Read Property * of Undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular8

How do I declare and utilize Interfaces in Angular Karma Jasmine unit test? The following is giving error, it is stating undefined for the first property of interface; trying to get the component running

> Cannot read property of 'primaryPropertyMailingAddressId' of undefined

**Karma/Jasmine:**

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PropertySitusFinalizeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    component.jsonData = {};  // removing or keeping this line does not change the error message

    fixture.detectChanges();

  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

**Component:**

```
export class PropertySitusFinalizeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() jsonData: PropertySitusAddressContainer;
```

**Interface:**

```
export interface PropertySitusAddressContainer {
  queueItemId?: number;
  existingPropertySitusAddress?: PropertySitusAddress;  

export class PropertySitusAddress {

    primaryPropertyMailingAddressId?:number = null;
    propertyId?: number = null;
    propertySitusAddressId?: number = null;
    addressFormatId?: number = null; 
    apn?: string = null;
```

Resource:

[How to unit test model interfaces in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907035/how-to-unit-test-model-interfaces-in-typescript)

Comment: Can you post the complete code, preferably in a Stackblitz? Other than that, `PropertySitusAddress` does not seem to getting initialized and somewhere within your `PropertySitusAddress` you try to access it (`component.propertySitusAddress.primaryPropertyMailingAddressId`), hence an `of undefined` error pops up. (You do *NOT* need to initialize the values as jithil suggests, just a double-check that it's defined when you try to access it (!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the values:

`@Input() jsonData: PropertySitusAddressContainer = {
      existingPropertySitusAddress = {}
}`

this way, all the fields which accessed using `.` operators need to be initialized.

In your html, use `value = "jsonData?.existingPropertySitusAddress?.primaryPropertyMailingAddressId"` will be a good option for `type safety`.